# Pause video when not in view swiper.js

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, swiper.js

I recently started using javascript swiper - https://swiperjs.com. I made the slides to contain html videos. The problem is that if I play a video and then swipe for another slide it (logically) keeps playing in the background and I felt it is a bit annoying. How should I make the videos pause when they’re not in view?

Basic call of the swiper -

```
// SWIPER SERVICES START
if (document.body.id === "services") {
  const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    loop: true,
    speed: 600,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 15000,
    },
    // Optional parameters
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop: true,
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: {
      el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
  });
}
// SWIPER SERVICES END
```

Slides looking like this

```
 <div class="swiper-slide">
      <p class="note date">2023</p>
      <p class="note">
        <a
          href="https://video.dk/“
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
          ><span>Showreel</span
          ><span
            >&nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square"></i
          ></span>
        </a>
      </p>
      <video
        src="/img/showreel.mp4"
        preload="metadata"
        controls="controls"
        playsinline
        role="video"
        aria-label=“label”
        aria-describedby="<?php echo $lang['asset_40'] ?>"
        poster="/img/cover"
      ></video>
    </div>
```

I'm looking forward to read your meaningful non toxic input.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event slideChange that you can listen for and pause the video accordingly.

Here is a modified version of your code :

```js
// SWIPER SERVICES START
if (document.body.id === "services") {
  const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    loop: true,
    speed: 600,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 15000,
    },
    direction: "horizontal",
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    scrollbar: {
      el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
    on: {
      slideChange: function () {
        // Pause videos in the previous slide
        const previousSlide = this.slides[this.previousIndex];
        pauseVideosInSlide(previousSlide);
      },
    },
  });
}

// Function to pause all videos in a given slide
function pauseVideosInSlide(slide) {
  const videos = slide.querySelectorAll('video');
  videos.forEach(video => {
    if (!video.paused) {
      video.pause();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot Reda!